# Opening a popup window based on selected dropdown option

Tags: html, forms, popup

What I'm trying to do is create a simple form with a dropdown list and a submit button. Upon selecting an option from the dropdown list, the user clicks the submit button and a popup window opens that allows them to view more info about the option they selected.

Right now I simply have:

```
<form action="example.php" method="post" target="_blank">
    <select size="7" name="identifier" style="width: 100%;">
        <option>
            Options....
        </option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Now this does 'work' as is in that when the user selects an option and presses submit, it opens a new window with the selected option post data passed along. However I would like it specifically to open a smaller popup window with a size I can define rather than a whole new window. I'm also aware target=_blank is deprecated so I'm wondering what would be the preferred way to achieve this now?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: I want to be able to pass along the form data however, not just open a new window. I may be wrong but it doesn't look like this method passes along the form data.

Comment: Is it really necessary to use a form? You can't change the size of the window when using target="_blank", see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541392/opening-new-window-in-html-for-target-blank

Comment: It is necessary to use a form, because the dropdown list is populated by events. When selecting an event and clicking 'submit' a popup window will appear where the user can view and edit details about the selected event.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link that may be solve your problem (stackoverflow Link) : [how to show popup if select "option" in "select" dropdown using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649072/how-to-show-popup-if-select-option-in-select-dropdown-using-javascript)

Comment: I want to be able to pass along the form data however, not just open a new window. I may be wrong but it doesn't look like this method passes along the form data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<form action="example.php" method="post" target='popup' onsubmit="window.open('','popup','width=700,height=400,left=200,top=200,scrollbars=1')">
```

Or add this code to your submit button :
   onclick="window.open('','popup','width=700,height=400,left=200,top=200,scrollbars=1')"

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work as it does not pass along the form data.

Answer (score 0):

`onsubmit` call a javascript function.
in that function get all the values you need to pass 
e.g. `var myelementval = document.getElementById('myelement')`
then use

```
window.open('mywindow.php?myelement='+myelementval,"mypopupname","width=500,height=400,resizable=yes,top=100,left=200,scrollbars=yes" 
.........
```